# Push Notification Jitsi Call in Flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, jitsi-meet

I am looking for a solution to implement push notification for an incoming Call with jitsi_meet in my flutter app even if the app is in background or closed. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

use connectycube package it is the best and it works in the background
[connectycube callkit](https://pub.dev/packages/connectycube_flutter_call_kit) follow the instructions